# Loop creates undefined item

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
var instrukceTexty = [
  ["Nadpis", "Text instrukce"],
  ["Nadpis 2", "Text instrukce 2"],
  ["Nadpis 3", "lorem"]
];

function zobrazInstrukci (  ) {
  var obrazovka;

  for ( var i = 0; i < instrukceTexty.length; i += 1 ) {
    obrazovka += '<div><h1>' + instrukceTexty[i][0] + '</h1>';
    obrazovka += '<p>' + instrukceTexty[i][1] + '</p></div>';
  }

  document.write( obrazovka );
}



zobrazInstrukci(instrukceTexty);
```

If you run it before first div is text undefined. I cant find out why.

Comment: Just a side note!!, document.write is not really an ideal way to manipulate the DOM, for small things like this not much of an issue, but be aware if you application gets bigger I would suggest avoiding doing this.

Answer (score 6):

Because you are appending to `undefined`.

Replace this line

```
var obrazovka;
```

with

```
var obrazovka = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initialising the variable 'obrazovka' with no value so it technically has the value undefined. Your then appending the html onto undefined.

```
// equivalent to var obrazovka = undefined;
var obrazovka;
```

One solution is to initialise this variable with a default value e.g.

```
var obrazovka = "";
```

Or if you have the ability to use ES2015 features then set it as a default parameter of your function e.g.

```
function zobrazInstrukci (instrukceTexty = [], obrazovka = "" ) {

  for ( var i = 0; i < instrukceTexty.length; i += 1 ) {
    obrazovka += '<div><h1>' + instrukceTexty[i][0] + '</h1>';
    obrazovka += '<p>' + instrukceTexty[i][1] + '</p></div>';
  }

  document.write( obrazovka );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `obrazovka` was declared but not initialized.  Trying to use an uninitialized variable as string will return the string 'undefined'.

To fix that, simply give it a string value of nothing. `var obrazovka='';` and your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var instrukceTexty = [
  ["Nadpis", "Text instrukce"],
  ["Nadpis 2", "Text instrukce 2"],
  ["Nadpis 3", "lorem"]
];

function zobrazInstrukci (instrukceTexty) {
  var obrazovka='';

  for ( var i = 0; i < instrukceTexty.length; i += 1 ) {
    obrazovka += '<div><h1>' + instrukceTexty[i][0] + '</h1>';
    obrazovka += '<p>' + instrukceTexty[i][1] + '</p></div>';
  }

  document.write( obrazovka );
}
zobrazInstrukci(instrukceTexty);
```

Function parameter missing, try this code